# Parsing command line options in Jython 2.1

Tags: python, websphere, jython, websphere-6.1, wsadmin

I'm using Jython 2.1 for wsadmin scripting and want to find a better way of parsing command line options. I'm currently doing this:

`-> deploy.py foo bar baz`

and then  in the script:

```
foo = sys.arg[0]
bar = sys.arg[1]
baz = sys.arg[2]
```

but would like to do this:

`-> deploy.py -f foo -b bar -z baz`

[optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) was added to python in 2.3. What other options do I have in Jython 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
args = sys.argv[:]  # Copy so don't destroy original
while len(args) > 0:
    current_arg = args[0]

    if current_arg == '-f':
        foo = args[1]
        args = args[2:]
    elif current_arg == '-b':
        bar = args[1]
        args = args[2:]
    elif current_arg == '-z':
        baz = args[1]
        args = args[2:]
    else:
        print 'Unknown argument: %r' % args[0]
        args = args[1:]
```

Disclaimer: Not tested in any way.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed a small error sys.args should've been sys.argv. I was looking for an api but this simple (and in retrospect obvious!) solution works and is  plenty enough for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The getopt library is bundled with Jython 2.1. It's not as fancy as the newer argument parsing modules, but still much better than rolling your own argument parsing.

`import getopt`

Documentation for getopt: http://docs.python.org/release/2.1.1/lib/module-getopt.html

I'm using it under WebSphere Appserver 7.0.0.x. I see you've tagged this question with websphere-6.1 - unfortunately I don't have a WAS 6.1 system at hand to test right now.

EDIT: Verified on WebSphere 6.1; getopt is present.

Answer (score 1):

Note that most libraries are actually simple Python modules that you can find under \Lib in your Python distribution, so often a simple file copy will give you the library.

In this case, I copied optparse.py (with its dependency textparse.py) from Python 2.7 to Jython 2.2, and it seems to import just fine.

Comment: Thanks, It's a possibility but I'm not about to add unsupported dependencies to a production server, especially WebSphere :)